# Must implement interface > Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface, none given in __construct() function

Tags: 8, entities, event-subscribers

I am trying to write a custom eventsubscriber for commerce 2.x for an event after a successful checkout. Everything works and now I want to create a `__construct` function to initialize an object, but then I get the following error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber\OrderCompleteEventSubscriber::__construct()
>   must implement interface
>   Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface, none given, called in
>   /home/user/websiteName/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php
>   on line 264 in Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber\OrderCompleteEventSubscriber->__construct()

I've tried explicitly defining the `EntityTypeManagerInterface` within the class, but everything is resulting in this error. Not finding anyone with any similar issues, and this particular block of code works for other people, just wondering what I am missing or If I am doing something incorrect. This code runs great if I don't construct an object with `EntityTypeManagerInterface`as the argument ... any ideas?

```
namespace Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Drupal\Core\StringTranslation\StringTranslationTrait;
use Drupal\rng\RegistrantFactoryInterface;
use Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;


class OrderCompleteEventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  use StringTranslationTrait;

  /**
   * The registration entity storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageInterface
   */
  protected $registrationStorage;

  /**
   * The user entity storage.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\user\UserStorage
   */
  protected $userStorage;

  /**
   * The registration access handler.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityAccessControlHandlerInterface
   */
  protected $registrationAccessHandler;

  /**
   * The registrant factory.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\rng\RegistrantFactoryInterface
   */
  protected $registrantFactory;

  /**
   * Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface definition.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface
   */
  protected $currentUser;

  /**
   * Constructs a new OrderCompleteEventSubscriber object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager
   * @param \Drupal\rng\RegistrantFactoryInterface $registrantFactory
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface $current_user
   */
  public function __construct(EntityTypeManagerInterface $entity_type_manager, RegistrantFactoryInterface $registrantFactory, AccountProxyInterface $current_user) {
    $this->registrationStorage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('registration');
    $this->registrationAccessHandler = $entity_type_manager->getAccessControlHandler('registration');
    $this->userStorage = $entity_type_manager->getStorage('user');
    $this->registrantFactory = $registrantFactory;
    $this->currentUser = $current_user;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    return [
      'commerce_order.place.post_transition' => ['buildRegistration'],
    ];
  }

  /**
   *
   * @param \Drupal\state_machine\Event\WorkflowTransitionEvent $event
   */
  public function buildRegistration(WorkflowTransitionEvent $event) {
    $order = $event->getEntity();
    // do stuff
      }
    }
  }

}
```

`Services.yml` File

```
services:
   custom_module_event_subscriber:
      class: '\Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber\OrderCompleteEventSubscriber'
      tags:
        - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

Comment: Probably the arguments in the service definition are missing, can you show the content of the *.services.yml file?

Comment: @4k4 that might be it, I did not provide arguments in my services file :P
I have put my `services.yml` file up

Comment: yes, you need this line: `arguments: ['@entity_type.manager', '@...', '@...']`

Comment: @4k4 That worked and cleared up the issue with the `EntityTypeManagerInterface` issue. Thanks! Where did you come up with `entity_type.manager` instead of `entity_type_manager`?  I am going through the docs and am not finding too many useful things on arguments. My second argument is now throwing an error saying the services has a dependency on a non-existent service, but when i take it out of the `services.yml`, the program white screens with the error saying I need my second argument to be of that type which symphony says it doesn't exist so I can't clear caches.

Comment: The services are named arbitrarily, you have to look them up. You find the core services in `core.services.yml`. The second service is from a module, so you find this in `rng.services.yml` of that module.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but the code from EventSubscriber has three arguments so your services.yml file should read:

```
services:
  custom_module.order_complete:
    class: Drupal\custom_module\EventSubscriber\PurchaseBuildRegistration
    arguments: ['@entity_type.manager', '@rng.registrant.factory', '@current_user']
tags:
  - { name: event_subscriber }
```